# The W3C Markup Validation Service says a <body> tag is not allowed

Tags: html, validation, w3c

When validating my page (https://www.slamgmt.com), it says:
document type does not allow element "body" here
The body tag is the only tag in the HTML root tag other than the head tag.  I have no idea why it's failing.
The change that caused this was switching from XHTML1.0 Strict to XHTML1.0 Frameset.  It validates in Strict, but not in the looser Frameset?  I'm so confused.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that XHTML1.0 Frameset is "looser"? It's not, it's just different. It's for pages with frames.

Comment: Looks like I was confusing Transitional and Frameset.  Whoops

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Frameset documents contain a `<frameset>` not `<body>`.

It is *Transitional* that is Strict + things that should generally be avoided.

- *Strict* — modern documents
- *Transitional* — documents partially converted from 1995 code to modern code
- *Frameset* — framesets

Comment: That did it.  My page is strict throughout except for one iframe I had to add.  It sucks I have to go to the less strict version just for some external content. Thanks!